# Scrape table data from html page

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table

I want to scrape data from a website.

```
<table class="responsive r-640">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="lm" scope="col">Name</th>
        <th class="lm" scope="col">Country</th>
        <th class="lm" scope="col">Games</th>
        <th class="lm" scope="col">Sport » Event</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="first-item">
        <td class="lt" rowspan="1" data-label="Name"><a href="/results/athletes/45380">A. Cole</a></td>
        <td class="lt" data-label="Country">Canada</td>
        <td class="lt" data-label="Games">1954</td>
        <td class="lt" data-label="Sport » Event">Road Race - Men</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="first-item">
        <td class="lt" rowspan="2" data-label="Name"><a href="/results/athletes/41872">A. Corlett</a></td>
        <td class="lt" data-label="Country">Isle of Man</td>
        <td class="lt" data-label="Games">1970</td>
        <td class="lt" data-label="Sport » Event">Singles - Women</td>
    </tr>
```

I want the data in a table with headers Name, URL, Country, Games,  Sport. how can I scrape the data in this format

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
import pandas as pd

html = '''
<table class="responsive r-640">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="lm" scope="col">Name</th>
        <th class="lm" scope="col">Country</th>
        <th class="lm" scope="col">Games</th>
        <th class="lm" scope="col">Sport » Event</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="first-item">
        <td class="lt" rowspan="1" data-label="Name"><a href="/results/athletes/45380">A. Cole</a></td>
        <td class="lt" data-label="Country">Canada</td>
        <td class="lt" data-label="Games">1954</td>
        <td class="lt" data-label="Sport » Event">Road Race - Men</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="first-item">
        <td class="lt" rowspan="2" data-label="Name"><a href="/results/athletes/41872">A. Corlett</a></td>
        <td class="lt" data-label="Country">Isle of Man</td>
        <td class="lt" data-label="Games">1970</td>
        <td class="lt" data-label="Sport » Event">Singles - Women</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

'''

dfs = pd.read_html(html)
df = dfs[0]
display(df)
```

This will return:

```
Name    Country Games   Sport » Event
0   A. Cole Canada  1954.0  Road Race - Men
1   A. Corlett  Isle of Man 1970.0  Singles - Women
2   A. Corlett  NaN NaN NaN
```